# Ajax call from django template

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates, django-views

I have a django template which extends the base template that has code to load jquery in it. This template has a simple text box and I wanted to fetch the object through ajax.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form id="ajaxform">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="dataDiv">

</div>

<script>
    $('#ajaxform').submit(function(){
        console.log('Form submitted');
        $.get('{% url get_ajax_data %}', $(this).serialize(),function(data){
            $('#dataDiv').text(data);

        })
        return false;
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

In this template, I tried to make ajax call to the get_ajax_data url and in the corresponding view I simply returned text as `return HttpResponse('Ajax respose')`. But this does not seem to work and the form gets submitted while I have returned false. I am not sure where I missed.

Comment: always use something like `$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });`. Please give more detail on errors you see. Right now your question is very hard to answer.

Comment: I tried adding $(document).ready but it does not seem to work. The main problem is that the form gets submitted which should not be since I have done return false in ``submit``.

Comment: I figured out. There was a semicolon missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till was on to the answer,  Common practice is to initialize the `submit()` handler.  This is done by setting it when the page is ready.  Currently you have it to submit the form the regular way, it's not even registering with your javascript.  To fix it you could write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ajax_form').submit(fun // the rest of your code here.
});
```

Comment: I figured out the mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's not technically correct. While it's best practice to use `$(document).ready()`, as long as the javascript is *after* all elements affected by it and jQuery is already initialized, there shouldn't be any problems. Most likely, jQuery was being loaded at the bottom of the page and this JavaScript was ahead of jQuery being available.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery event handlers fail silently if there's an error in them. Check for the obvious things like missing semicolons, etc. Make sure everything is valid in the event handler and it should work.

Comment: I was doing wrong and having some mistake myself but it didnot have any error log in the console. It was the problem. There were no error log and so I assumed it to be correct and thought there are some other ways to respond to ajax. Thank you very much for pointing this behavior. This will help me lot for debugging.